# Can't call JS function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<input type="checkbox" id="PM" style="float: left;" onclick="ValidateCheckBox(this)" />


<script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidateCheckBox(source) {
    alert("HERE!")
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('AMPM');
    checkbox1.checked = false;
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('AM');
    checkbox2.checked = false;
    var checkbox3 = document.getElementById('PM');
    checkbox3.checked = false;
    $(source).attr('checked', true);

    var hdn1 = document.getElementById('timeAMPM');
    var hdn2 = document.getElementById('timeAM');
    var hdn3 = document.getElementById('timePM');

    hdn1.value = checkbox1.checked;
    hdn2.value = checkbox2.checked;
    hdn3.value = checkbox3.checked;
}
</script>
```

cannot call JS function. I tried with onchange too. Now I add the hole function. I have 3 checkboxes and what I want is always to be checked only one!
I got an error in the console of the browser : RefferenceError: $document is not defined

Comment: Have you tried pasting your script above the input ?

Comment: @Eregrith It is called with `(this)`, so the input appears to be passed.

Comment: This will work as it is.  You may have an error elsewhere in your code which causes the JS not to parse. http://jsfiddle.net/gUusk/ Check your error console.

Comment: That's not what I was asking.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I have `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'alert' of object [object Window] is not a function ` with your example; I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m

Comment: @Eregrith Very weird indeed.  21.0.1180.89 on Linux works exactly as expected for me.

Comment: I disabled `Better Pop Up Blocker` but it did not change the result or the error...

Comment: It works for me too in Chrome 21.0.1180.89 on Mac OS

Comment: true! I've got an error, shown in the error console of the browser: RefferenceError: $document is not defined